# How does a apt repository work to find the available packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, postgresql

For example i have this apt ubuntu (21.10) [repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) for postgres in my `sources.list.d`:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ impish-pgdg main 13
```

Which results in `apt-get update` to fetch:

```
Hit:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg InRelease
Get:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [247 kB]
```

By default the shown packages for example via `apt-cache policy postgresql-plpython3-13` only show the latest minor version of that package (= 13.5):

```
postgresql-plpython3-13:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 13.5-1.pgdg100+1
  Version table:
     13.5-1.pgdg100+1 500
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
```

I took a deep look inside the repository structure and found various older minor versions for those packages located in:
[`http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-13/`](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-13/)

A part of the directory structure is like:

```
dists/
  impish-pgdg/
  (...)
    13/
    main/
    InRelease
    Release
    (...)
pool/
  main/
    p/
    (...)
      postgresql-13/
      (...)
        postgresql-plpython3-13_13.5-1.pgdg100%2B1_amd64.deb
        (...)
```

- **Question:** How is the algorithm where apt searches for packages? How can i tell apt or configure my source list entry to show/remember all minor versions of a package available on the repository?

For example the package above in version `13.1`, not `13.5`?

Answer (score 1):

Really APT first scans *dists* folder. In your case it is http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/ .

It fetches [InRelease](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/InRelease) to determine available components:

> ```
> Components: main 9.6 10 11 12 13 14
> ```

So you will get the packages defined in *Packages* file of the [main](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages), [9.6](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/9.6/binary-amd64/Packages), [10](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/10/binary-amd64/Packages), [11](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/11/binary-amd64/Packages), [12](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/12/binary-amd64/Packages), [13](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/13/binary-amd64/Packages), [14](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/14/binary-amd64/Packages) versions.

The [Packages file for 13](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/impish-pgdg/13/binary-amd64/Packages) exactly contain fields:

> ```
> Version: 13.5-1.pgdg21.10+1
> ```

so this is why 13.5 is available from `main 13` *sources.list* line.

Comment: So this means there is no way to get the other (older) versions from the subdirectory inside `pool` to be listed by apt when these versions are not part of the _Packages_ file(s)?

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. See details at https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format .